# How to create a custom key modifier in Mac OS X for Custom Keyboard

Tags: keyboard, applescript, keyboard-maestro

I'm buying a keyboard from logitech: Logitech Tablet Keyboard for Android. I want to use it for my macbook.

The keyboard does not have "command" key on it, it only have the "search" key replacement for the "command" key before the "space bar" key and after the "alt" key. But the "search" key does not work as the "command" key, which it also does not identified in mac keyboard preference.

So I try to use Keyboard Maestro, cannot found any feature to remap the "search" key to "command" key. Then I try to use Apple Script in Keyboard Maestro as in below screenshot, but it's not working as I expected. When I press the "search" key + "z" that I guess should behave like "command" + "z", but it did not, I should press "search" key twice then "a", sometimes the "command" event still pressed so I cannot type anything after that.

Is there any way to make the "search" key remapped to "command" key?

### http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1550865/Keyboard_Maestro.png

http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1550865/Keyboard_Maestro-2.png

If the screenshot does not appear, please using below dropbox links:
1) http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1550865/Keyboard_Maestro.png
2) http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1550865/Keyboard_Maestro-2.png

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) in KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::Q, KeyCode::COMMAND_L</autogen>
```

If it works, open EventViewer.app and see if the search key has a normal key code. If it is for example 0x6e, change `KeyCode::Q` to `KeyCode::PC_APPLICATION`. It is also possible to add [device-specific settings](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml-devicedef.html.en).

See the source for [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).